# Magento2 : How to create group of fileds on admin config

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9

I am trying to create a group of options please see attached image [image]

I have tried by adding single field but it's creating separate filed, i need similar solution either in magento1 or magento2.

Comment: Yes, it can be possiable.

Comment: Could please help me ? is there any source for the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this requirement, you have to  create

### 1. frontend_model

This is a block which will render the field view  and it will extend `Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\FieldArray\AbstractFieldArray`

Example: `Devamitbera\Stackexchange\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\Groupcodes`.

### 2. backend_model

This is a model which saves that field value using **JSON serialized** and during this field value load using `_afterLoad` function, it converts field value to the array and during save using `beforeSave()` it converts the field to array from JSON.

**Example:**

```
<?php

namespace Devamitbera\Stackexchange\Model\System\Config\Backend;

/**
 * Backend for serialized array data
 */
class Groupcodes extends \Magento\Framework\App\Config\Value
{

    protected $ConvertverClass = null;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $config
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList
     * @param \Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Minsaleqty $catalogInventoryMinsaleqty
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $config,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList,
        \ConvertverClass $ConvertverClass,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->ConvertverClass = $ConvertverClass;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $config, $cacheTypeList, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Process data after load
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _afterLoad()
    {
        $value = $this->getValue();
        // This is class which Convert json to array
        $value = $this->ConvertverClass->functiontoConVertArrayFromSJson($value);
        $this->setValue($value);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare data before save
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function beforeSave()
    {
        $value = $this->getValue();
    // This is class which Convert json to array
        $value = $this->ConvertverClass->functiontoConVertJsonFromArray($value);
        $this->setValue($value);
    }
}
```

At this case, you can use the following `Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart`  which exits at  `admin>Store>Configuration>Catalog>Inventory> Product Stock Options>Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart`

**Reference:**

**system.xml** :  [system.xml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/CatalogInventory/etc/adminhtml/system.xml)

**Frontend Model class** [Magento\CatalogInventory\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\Minsaleqty;](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/CatalogInventory/Block/Adminhtml/Form/Field/Minsaleqty.php#L14)

**Model Class** [Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\System\Config\Backend\Minsaleqty](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/CatalogInventory/Model/System/Config/Backend/Minsaleqty.php#L6)